# Use ExcludeFromBuild with MSBuild/VisualStudio build customization

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have created a build customization for a custom file type I need to compile (PiPL *.r files).  However, when I open such a file's properties in Visual Studio, pick one of the configurations, and set "Excluded from build" to "Yes", Visual Studio still insists on compiling that file under that configuration.  In the vcxproj file, the `ExcludedFromBuild` property is correctly set on this file for that configuration;

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PIPLFile Include="..\MyFile.r">
    <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Test_Release|x64'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  </PIPLFile>
</ItemGroup>
```

When logging is set to 'Diagnostic', I get the following output:

> 1>Target "PIPLCompile" in file "[my path]\r.targets":
> 1>  Building target "PIPLCompile" completely.
> 1>  Input file "[my source path]\MyFile.r" is newer than output file "[my IntDir path]\Resources.pipl".

You'd think that MSBuild would pick up on this property automatically also for custom file types?  Or do build customizations need to check on this property themselves?

I've managed to 'solve' it by adding a condition to the `Exec` task which does the actual compiling, checking on `%(PIPLFile.ExcludedFromBuild)`.  But looking at the logs, MSBuild still wants to run this task each time because the input is newer than the output (a situation which will never resolve itself this way ofc).  I'd thus rather have MSBuild skipping the target completely, but you can't use metadata in a condition on the target level; it gives an error instead:

> error MSB4116: The condition "'%(PIPLFile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'" on the "PIPLCompile" target has a reference to item metadata.

Seeing how much I've so far struggled with the docs, Google, and trial-and-erroring the available options, I wouldn't be surprised if I've overlooked something basic though.  And related to this: if anyone spots anything funky or overly complex in the code below, I'd appreciate any hints on improving it in the comments :)

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, version 16.11.21; MSBuild is at version 16.11.2.50704

My current build customization is:

**r.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/build/2009/properties">
  <Rule Name="PIPLConfig" PageTemplate="generic" DisplayName="PiPL configuration">
    <Rule.Categories>
      <Category Name="PIPLGeneral" DisplayName="General" />
    </Rule.Categories>
    <Rule.DataSource>
      <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="PIPLFile" />
    </Rule.DataSource>
    <StringProperty Subtype="folder" Name="PIPLSDKPath" Category="PIPLGeneral" DisplayName="SDK path" Description="The path to the installed SDK." />
  </Rule>

  <ItemType Name="PIPLFile" DisplayName="PIPL File" />
  <ContentType Name="PIPLFile" ItemType="PIPLFile" DisplayName="PIPL File" />
  <FileExtension Name=".r" ContentType="PIPLFile" />
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

**r.targets** (a bit simplified here and there)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)r.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="PIPLFile">
      <Targets>PIPLCompile</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target
    Name="PIPLCompile"
    Inputs="@(PIPLFile);%(PIPLFile.RootDir)%(PIPLFile.Directory)%(PIPLFile.FileName).config"
    Outputs="@(PIPLFile -> '$(IntDir)pipl.rr');@(PIPLFile -> '$(IntDir)Resources.pipl')"
    BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
  >
    <Exec
      Condition="'%(PIPLFile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
      Command="&quot;$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64)\cl.exe&quot; /nologo /D &quot;PRWIN_ENV&quot; -I &quot;%(PIPLFile.PIPLSDKPath)\Headers&quot; /EP &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\%(PIPLFile.Filename).r&quot; &gt; &quot;$(IntDir)pipl.rr&quot;
&quot;%(PIPLFile.PIPLSDKPath)\Resources\PiPLtool.exe&quot; &quot;$(IntDir)pipl.rr&quot; &quot;$(IntDir)Resources.pipl&quot;"
      Outputs="$(IntDir)pipl.rr;$(IntDir)Resources.pipl"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is this for a C++ project?

Comment: The MSB4116 error is NOT because you used a property in a condition. Properties are allowed in Conditions. The error is because you are trying to use metadata, which is very different. See [target batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-metadata-in-target-batching?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Yes, it's for C++.  And me using `property` instead of `metadata` just shows how much I have yet to learn about msbuild :)  I'll update the post to correct this.

Comment: Instead of batching the compilation on the `PIPLFile.ExcludedFromBuild` metadata, you consider creating a new item collection. This would help with your Inputs/Outputs because currently you are including the files that are excluded from compilation.

Comment: Looking at the [Microsoft/VSProjectSystem](https://github.com/microsoft/VSProjectSystem) documentation, it seems geared towards new types of projects and the 'extend an existing type of project' doc is just a 'TODO'. If you are just trying to add a few steps to an existing project, you don't need to create a full VSProject extension.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Point is though that this custom file type is used in 140+ projects, so I'd rather have a single build customization than 140+ copies of how to handle PiPL files...  And I regretfully fail to see what creating a new item collection could bring, but that's probably more on me than on your suggestion.

Comment: To give some more context: all projects contain a single .r file, and the resulting .rr and .pipl files get picked up by the project's .rc file.  The project configuration determines whether both the .r files and .rc files participate in the build at all.  So if ExcludedFromBuild is true, the result of the .r files will not be expected by msbuild anyway (since it then doesn't process the .rc files either).

Comment: Let's move this to the chat and work together on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253888/discussion-between-jonathan-dodds-and-carl-colijn).